# What is the best way to prevent memory loss when clearing a php v5.6 array of strings

Tags: php, arrays, memory-leaks

In order to prevent memory loss and memory 'bottlenecks' I'm currently clearing/'marking for release' memory in a string array using:

```
//
// Clear each of the possibly thousands of long strings contained in the
// $strMAINs array elements and mark them for subsequent memory release.
// No other variables reference the strings in this array.
//

for( $c = ( count( $strMAINs ) - 1 ); $c >= 0; --$c ) {

    $strMAINs[  $c ] = '';
    unset( $strMAINs[  $c ] );

}

//
// Do the same for the overall array, unless the array is to reused before
// the overall code execution is complete.
//

$strMAINs = '';
unset( $strMAINs );

//
// Make an empty array with the same variable name available for subsequent
// use.
//

$strMAINs = [];  // Actually, this isn't needed.  Just don't clear the whole
                 // variable so the array can be reused!
```

However, at the end of the above code-chunk, the $strMAINs array is then re-assigned with a new empty, so that this variable is ready for subsequent assignments using

```
$strMAINs[] = some string value or string variable;
```

I saw other questions on this topic that recommend only using **unset( $*variable* );**, but then the answers don't address that the array **unset** doesn't immediately release the memory, but instead defers this until the end of the code's execution or memory becomes low enough to cause garbage collection to occur, which I think the latter is a big performance hit because it has to 'look' for as much pending no longer used variable memory as it can find, whereas any variables that are explicitly **'marked for released'** are probably easier to find and if after being released are enough to eliminate the overall low memory condition would optimize the garbage collection operation.

So, this leaves me with a few questions:

1. Does it actually help to assign empty strings, **''** or **NULL**, to
   each element when new values will be assigned to the elements?
   However, not necessarily the same number of elements, could be fewer
   or more.
2. If the element assignment loop is actually helpful, is there a better
   PHP function/statement to do the same thing that internalizes the
   execution of the whole looping and assignments in a single PHP
   interpreter processing step rather than a series of separate
   interpret/execute steps that are then individually processed?  Or, is
   the **$strMAINs = [];** assignment statement best and doesn't risk
   memory loss and releases the memory held by old elements quickly and
   reduce frequency that the the web-server get bogged down when garbage
   collection occurs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you assign something to a variable if it's an empty string or a null value or an empty value something is defined in the memory.

`unset` force immediate memory freeing. The garbage collector do the rest. So when you have an array and want to free the memory then unset the element.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Are you saying only the whole array unset in one step or the individual elements and then the whole array in multiple steps (to prevent/reduce memory loss)?  What about the memory not actually being reusable until garbage collection and the performance hit of garbage collection?

Comment: `unset($ret['test']);` then you remove the element from the array so that should be cleaned. In most cases you have to define the variable before otherwise your code is not well.

Comment: Thanks again.  So each element is unset in a loop.  After thinking some more on this the whole thing doesn't need to be unset because not doing this leaves the array available for subsequent use without needing the [] reassignment.